# Replacing random part of a generated key in Django

Tags: python, django, string, random, replace

I am generating a key in my Django project once a user clicks a button, here is the code in the view:

```
key_value = get_random_string(length=14, allowed_chars='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
 if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostProposal(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
[...]
p = Contract.objects.create(
               key= key_value,

[...]
```

The end result is a string of 14 characters, like this example: I8IH2GPH8RNK6A

I am trying to create another key: "key1" tha will replace randomly 4 characters by an underscore, so basically I will have:

> key: I8IH2GPH8RNK6A
>
> key1: I8I_2GP_8_NK_A

the replacement should be randomly created when the user clicks the button, and it always concern 4 characters. Any help would be appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
key = "I8IH2GPH8RNK6A"
key1 = list(key)
while 1:
    key1[random.randrange(0, len(key))] = "_"
    if key1.count("_") == 4:
        break
key1 = ''.join(key1)
print key1
```

Comment: @Riad C please check this

Comment: This can be improved by doing `while key1.count("_") != 4:` and remove `if key1.count("_") == 4:break` instead of `while 1:`

Comment: Thank you, it worked and @Lemayzeur, I used the improved one, but can you shed a light on the improvement version? and is there a way to avoid having two letter that are close to each other to be replaced by the "_" ?